# can we use all the desktop environment in Debian 8.5

Tags: debian, desktop

I install Debian 8.5 Jessie, but in the installation it show me Select and install Software exactly in the desktop environment.
[image]

After taking this photo, I selected all and install it.

Now, when I use debian, can I use all the desktop environments, how can I now switch between them ?
thank you

Comment: Did you notice the button `screenshot`?

Comment: Your image does not show that you selected all. If you missed some, then add them after install.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use all of them. Even some that are not even there!

You will have to install the ones you haven't included when installing Debian. A simple

```
$ apt-get install desktop-of-choice
```

will do the trick. You can also use the program "synaptic" if you want a graphical interface for installing new software.

In order to change between desktop environments you will have to log out and change it in the log in screen.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to install all the desktop systems and select the one you wish to use on the login screen. You should then also be able to set a default desktop environment to use.

I have never tried this myself, but I have a co-worker who set up his machine like that and it works fairly well. Only issues I have seen myself was when my wife accidently installed the Edubuntu Desktop on top of the KDE one.

Comment: I have done it. Also if you are using the more modern desktops with xxxx extension, then you can switch without logging out, or closing any other application.